# Extract column name of first non NA value in each row of my dataframe

Tags: r

My dataframe looks like this:

colnames:

```
state   city     name_of_company    11/22    11/23    11/24
ga    atlanta     name              NA       NA         1
ny    newyork     name              NA       .75        1
```

I am trying to create a new column that contains the dates that correspond to the first non NA value in each row. I have no clue how to do this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There will be more non-NA values after the first non-NA. 

The non-NA values represent business transactions, so the date of the first value is the date the company opened--which is what i need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No `max.col`? I am disappointed.  ;-)

```
names(dat[4:6])[max.col(!is.na(dat[4:6]), "first")]
#[1] "11/24" "11/23"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one possible solution

```
df$first_NA <- apply(df,1,function(x) names(which(which(!is.na(x))>3))[1])
```

Comment: Earlier answer for to get column name of first NA value, I edited it to get the first non-NA value column name.